# Channel Form (Safecracker) title query

Tags: safecracker

I'm using Channel Form (formerly Safecracker) to generate a new entry using inline error handling.

The issue I'm having is if there is a reserved (HTML) character in any of the fields - eg `'` - these are returned as html characters/entities - eg `&#39`;

For example:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any way to suppress this conversion during the form submission process?

Cole

Comment: I have nothing productive to add... but my Grandmother lives in Bo'ness. So, hi.

Answer (score 2):

Set the fields to type = none in the CP. I think by default they're XHTML.

Comment: Are they stored in the DB as HTML entities?  If so I would probably use a plugin to strip it out.